# Why doesn't my code catch Exception?

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = MyException String deriving (Show, Typeable)

instance Exception MyException

myExToString :: MyException -> String
myExToString (MyException msg) = msg

t :: ()
t = throw $ MyException "Msg"

main = catch (return t) (\e -> putStrLn $ myExToString e)
```

Why doesn't my program print `"Msg"`?

**Update:**

I changed the code:

```
io :: IO ()
io = catch (return t) (\e -> putStrLn $ myExToString e)

main = io >>= print
```

But still my code doesn't catch `MyException`? Why?

Comment: Your update is simpley wrong.  Compiling that code should/does result in `so: MyException "Msg"`.  Are you sure you recompiled?  If so then open a new question and fill in all the details including a copy-paste of code, compilation, execution, uname -a, and ghc --version.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson My update is correct. The handler `\e -> putStrLn ...` does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because Haskell is lazy, and you never use the result of `t`, so it is never evaluated and thus the exception isn't thrown.

Comment: Can you please answer my second question (see Update)?

Answer (score 3):

About "why the code below does not print the exception?":

```
io :: IO ()
io = catch (return t) (\e -> putStrLn $ myExToString e)

main = io >>= print
```

Here, `print` is causing the exception to be thrown when it forces `t` to be evaluated, but at that time there's no `catch` around. Try instead:

```
io :: IO ()
io = catch (return t >>= print) (\e -> putStrLn $ myExToString e)
    -- or simply:  catch (print t) (\e -> ....)
main = io
```

Comment: ... or use `throwIO` instead of `return . throw`.